# Conditional Formatting Excel document via VB6 (issue with overwriting formats)

Tags: vba, excel, vb6, conditional-formatting

I'm creating an Excel document at runtime that has a bunch of values I'd like to have conditionally formatted. In going through various attempts from scratch as well as using/modifying code outputted from the Excel's macro recorder, I'm having a consistent issue related to formatting overwrites.

I've posted a snippet of the code below and can say that I've tested to ensure my selection ranges are valid and appropriate for what I want conditionally formatted. There is some overlap but what's bizarre is that the first conditional format takes on just one property of the second conditional format. Meaning D5:End of the worksheet ends up having a green color font as opposed to the red it should be. Commenting each section of the code does allow them to work independently but I'm guessing this is an issue with specifying conditional formats further somehow? I've tried a few different case scenarios and below is the code with modifications:

EDIT (Updated Code):

```
'First conditional format, check sheet for values > 50 and make text red.
With xl.range("D5:" & theLastColumn & lastRow)
  .FormatConditions.add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=50"
  With .FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
  .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With


'Second conditional format, check specific row (row 5 in the example) 
'for values > 40, and fill interior with green in addition to dark green text.
With xl.range("D" & Infectivity & ":" & theLastColumn & Infectivity)
  .FormatConditions.add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=40"
  With .FormatConditions(2).Font
    .Color = -16752384
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
  With .FormatConditions(2).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
  End With
End With
```

So what's the best way to have multiple conditional formats (that may overlap ranges) and still have them all function as intended? I've tried debugging this so much I'm certain there's something easy I'm overlooking. I've also tried a few different methods to specify separate formatconditions(1) and formatconditions(2) but still receive strange issues.

EDIT:

VBA Code where I continue to have the same issue.

```
Sub conditionalFormat()
  With Range("D5:BA9")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=50"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1).Font
      .Color = -16383844
      .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
  End With

  With Range("D9:BA9")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=40"
    With .FormatConditions(2).Font
      .Color = -16752384
      .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With .FormatConditions(2).Interior
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
      .Color = 13561798
      .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = False
  End With    
End Sub
```

Even with the SetFirstPriority on the appropriate (red text) conditional format, it just gets overwritten somehow. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am trying to understand this. You can help me by giving an example. Let's say the first range is `A1:G1` and the 2nd range is `D1:J1` so there is an over lap on `D1:G1`. So what are you expecting?

Comment: I'm just getting a lot of mixed results where the area that isn't overlapping still receives strange conditional formatting related to the second conditional format. I'm sorry it's a bit difficult to understand but I'll try to mockup an example in my original post.

Comment: Yeah Conditional Formatting can be a PIA if not handled properly... Will wait for your example.

Comment: I'm doing a bit more testing to see if I can figure out why **only** a portion of the formatting from one conditional format is being applied elsewhere. It's a bit frustrating when you're dealing with something as simple as a font color (and you're red/green color deficient). Regardless, thank you for the willingness to help @SiddharthRout. I look forward to your assistance.

Comment: Just to be sure.. Which excel version are you using?

Comment: Excel 2007. I should mention I've read a few mixed things about colors in 2007 (mainly stating to use RGB values). Using RGB values I still end up with the same results.

Comment: There must be something bizarre going on with how vb6 is referencing conditional formats. I've had my formats working just fine in the VBA editor but when porting it over it seems to go haywire. Worst case scenario I may be able to figure out a way to inject the VB code into the excel file and run the macro that way. Certainly not desirable though...

Comment: wait :) First things first... Are you latebinding or early binding with Excel from vb6?

Comment: Using latebinding... would earlybinding be better suited for doing this type of conditional formatting?

Comment: in that case, have you defined the constants `xlCellValue`, `xlGreater`, `xlAutomatic`, `xlThemeColorAccent3` ?

Comment: My apologies... we used to use latebinding on this form but it was switched to earlybinding.

Comment: Are you sure it is early binding? If not then see the edit in my post

Comment: Yes, it is early binding which continues to baffle me. Thank you very much for all the continued help @SiddharthRout. I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok the current vba code that you have, does it work?

Comment: In testing the code via the macro editor, I'm now seeing the same issue. I'll update my post one more time with the VBA code that doesn't work currently.

Comment: Did you test my code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38631/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-bernard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thought and reworking the code we came to the conclusion that what I was doing (multiple conditions overlapping) was the cause of the mixed results. At the simplest level, I was able to add .FormatConditions.Delete to my additional conditional formats to ensure only one format was applied.

The corrected final code is shown below:

```
Dim Infectivity As Long
Infectivity = Application.WorksheetFunction.match("Infectivity", range("A1:" & "A" & lastRow), 0)

With xl.range("D5:" & theLastColumn & lastRow)
    .FormatConditions.add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=50"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
With .FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With

If Infectivity > 0 Then
With xl.range("D" & Infectivity & ":" & theLastColumn & Infectivity)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
     Formula1:="=40"
With .FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16752384
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
End If
```

My downfall was related to the macro recorder giving me a false of the ideal method of formatting these cells. It's always best to simplify before moving forward.

Major thanks to Siddharth Rout for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. I don't have Excel 2007. Tested this in Excel 2010.

When it comes to conditional formatting, you have to be really careful of what the macro recorder spits out. This is one particular case where it makes a mess of the code.

Also you are setting then 2nd rule as `.SetFirstPriority` which is incorrect besides letting the 2nd rule run in spite of `rule 1` get getting satisfied :)

Here is a very basic example. Let's say my range looks like this `D5:G7`

[image]

Now this is the VBA code that I tested

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("D5:G7")

    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
        Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=50"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Color = -16776961
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True

        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
        Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=40"
        With .FormatConditions(2).Font
            .Color = -11489280
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(2).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
            .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

And this is the result that I got.

[image]

I am sure it will be very easy for you to port the above code to vb6.

FOLOWUP (From Comments)

> Using latebinding... would earlybinding be better suited for doing this type of conditional formatting? – Bernard 2 mins ago

If you are using LateBinding then declare this code at the top of your code

```
Const xlCellValue as Long = 1
Const xlGreater as Long = 5
Const xlAutomatic as Long = -4105
Const xlThemeColorAccent3 as Long = 7
```

Comment: I'm going to re-edit my original post with the updated code I'm using but still having the same issue. Somehow the first conditional format (applied to D5:end of sheet) uses green text instead of red. It has something to do with the second format somehow (despite it not being in that range). Commenting out the second range selection/formatting allows the red text to appear correctly. And commenting out the first range selection/formatting allows the second conditional format to work properly. They just don't play well with each other together.

Comment: see my comment in your post.