# Conditional Formatting using COUNTIF

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible in Excel using VBA to add a conditional formatting rule that uses the formula: `=COUNTIF(A1:B1,"*9.65*")`?

Comment: Use the macro recorder and see if it's possible (i.e. what have you tried ?)

Comment: When it comes to conditional formatting, you have to be really careful of what the macro recorder spits out. [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183902/conditional-formatting-excel-document-via-vb6-issue-with-overwriting-formats) is a scenario where it messes it. [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143603/vba-excel-apply-conditional-formatting-to-blank-cells) is another example on how to use formulas in conditional formatting. If you search stackoverflow, you will find many examples on how to use a formula in conditional formatting.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the formula to do? Are the values in A1:B1 numbers? `COUNTIF` won't allow wildcards with numbers

Answer (score 0):

VBA does faster what you can do manually, nothing more (well, it does something more, but that's just for experts :) ).

The answer to your question is yes if you can do it manually, no otherwise.

You try to manually do the formatting you need, either selecting a range and clicking on any formatting button or selecting each cell and applying it's color manually, one by one. Do it while recording a macro, and if you can do it manually then you can make a VBA function to do it for you quickly.

The recorded macro very likely will not work for you, but will be a good starting point for your real working macro.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can simply record a macro to get the approximate code that you need.

```
' For this example, the cell references are hard coded. Edit as required.
Range("D1:D4").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=COUNTIF(A1:B1,""9.65"")"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    ' This is the style that you apply to each cell.
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```